# The difference about the distribution format of GCC！

Tags: gcc

I wonder the other major difference about the distribution format of GCC between its source code and its precompiled binary code, except for the former can be customized installation(including cross-compiler) but the latter cannot！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wonder the other major difference about the distribution format

Distribution format has nothing to do with your question.

The differences are exactly the same as for any other program: if you have source code, you can debug, customize, or modify the program; if you only have binary, you can't (except to the degree that the program author has envisioned and explicitly programmed for).